# css3又はjQueryで1秒停止後再びアニメーションが続くようにしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

以下のように、css3アニメーションで 1.7秒かけてclass="n1"内の画像を1倍～1.5倍に拡大してフェードアウトで消えるようにしています。
これに、停止をいれたいのですがうまくいきません。
class="n1"を1秒停止後、0.7秒かけて「scaleout 」アニメーション（n1内の画像が1倍～1.5倍に拡大する）をしたいのですが、css3または、jQueryでどのようにしたらよいでしょうか。教えてください。

```
***  html  ***
<li class="n1"><img src="img/01.jpg" alt=""></li>


***  css  ***
.n1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.n1 {
  -webkit-animation: scaleout 1.7s ease-in-out;
  animation: scaleout 1.7s ease-in-out;
}

/* keyframe 始点から終点の設定 */
@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) 
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  } 
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  } 
 100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`transition-delay` (遅延)を使いましょう。`transition` でいうと第4パラメータです。

以下の例では、画像にマウスを重ねるとアニメーションを開始します(マウスを画像から外すと元に戻る)。scaleoutに相当する `transform` へのアニメーションは、1秒の遅延後に0.7秒かけて適用しているので、正味1.7秒です。画像を消すための `opacicty` へのアニメーションは、1.7秒の遅延後に0秒で適用するので、先のscaleout終了後に消えるような効果になっています。

余談ですが、opacittyの適用時間を長くすればフワッと消える感じになります。また、消した後は、同様の考え方で `display` や `visibility` プロパティも変更したほうが良いかもしれません。

```css
.n1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition:
    transform 0.7s ease-in-out 1.0s,
    opacity 0s ease 1.7s;
}
```

```html
<img class="n1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE90I.jpg?s=328&g=1">
```

なお説明をわかりやすくするために、このスニペットにはベンダープレフィックスをつけていません。よってブラウザ次第では正しく動作しない可能性がありますが、Chrome 43では正しく動作することを確認してあります。

Comment: @KoRoNさま、お返事遅くなりましてすみません。回答を当方のcssに置き換えて実行してみた所、質問のscaleoutと同じような結果が得られました。ありがとうございました！！！そして・・・スニペットを実行したらカピバラだったのでウケました。お蔭で楽しく勉強させていただきました。